# Simplify multiple fresh installs onto different hardware

Tags: system-installation, multiple-machines

I've read through this: [Is this a safe way to migrate my data to a new computer?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/707610) but most of the discussion is over my head. My computer usage has greatly declined since retiring 10 years ago, and I haven't kept up. I'm primarily a command line user, since the mid 80's.

I'm looking to greatly simplify my process for putting fresh single-user installs onto new hard drives in my various computers (all amd64 desktops/laptops, different videos cards etc), plus hopefully producing a custom live-dvd.  Old hard drives will get archived.   Some machines are not networked in anyway. All the hardware is old, e.g. 10-yrs. Last time I went through this was maybe 5 years ago.

First phase is the fundamental installation to create a bootable machine, Debian 11.7 with XFCE, with machine specific customizations such as partitioning, and generic customizations such as including/excluding various packages.

Second phase is a bunch of customizations, such as non-graphical login, sudoers list, fstab, gpg, additional package installs using apt, software config files, etc.

In the past I've kept a written log of these details on the first install, then tried to manually follow the log for subsequent installs.

Is there a simple auto-log feature or some such, especially the second phase? something more encompassing than bash-history?  Or a way to to create a system-diff between end-of-phase-one and the end-of-phase-two, then apply that diff on subsequent machines?

Comment: is debian's *installation preseeding* mechanism maybe what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks. The ornery part is Phase 2, but preseed ought to help with Phase 1, especially with [this](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed#Obtaining_the_answers_given_during_an_interactive_installer_run):  _The DebianInstaller logs the answers given during an interactive installation which can then be used to preseed a noninteractive installation_. And the preseed might be able to move additional package installs from Ph2 to Ph1

Comment: ah, and another trick: if you're going that route, use your primary workstation to set up a VM as the "master installation", i.e. to log the answers. Much nicer than doing it directly on a physical machine.